# Is there any tools or algorithms for convert 3D Point Cloud to 2.5D image?

Tags: python, 3d, 2.5d

I am looking for an algorithm for convert 3D Point Cloud to Depth Image in Python, especially 3D Face Point Cloud. Can you suggest me some tools or algorithms? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you search online for that? There are several algorithms and equations available. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294173/7919597

Comment: Thank you very much, it took me a lot of time kaka