# How can I draw using pygame, while also drawing with pyopengl?

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

I have a program that is written in python and uses pygame along with pyopengl. The only problem is, I can't draw anything on the screen with pygame.draw which is what I was going to use for interfacing with my program. I would like to know if there is a way to draw using pygame's system while also drawing 3D using pyopengl behind it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that directly.

However you can draw on a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with the [`pygame.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html) module or [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit). Use [`pygame.PixelArray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html) to access the pixels on the surface directly. Use the pixels to generate an OpenGL [Texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture) object. This texture can be used in OpenGL.

```py
def surfaceToTexture(pygame_surface):
    rgba_surface = pygame.image.tostring(pygame_surface, 'RGBA')
    width, height = pygame_surface.get_size()
    texture_obj = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_obj)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rgba_surface)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)
    return texture_obj

image = pygame.image.load('my_image.png')
texture = surfaceToTexture(image)
```

In the other direction you can render into a OpenGL [Renderbuffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Renderbuffer_Object) or  [Texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture) object (see [Framebuffers](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers)). Load the texture from the GPU with [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) or [`glGetTexImage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml) and create a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) with [`pygame.image.frombuffer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.frombuffer).

```py
size = screen.get_size()
buffer = glReadPixels(0, 0, *size, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
pygame.display.flip()
screen_surf = pygame.image.fromstring(buffer, size, "RGBA")
```

```py
image_buffer = glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
image_surf = pygame.image.fromstring(image_buffer, (width, height), "RGBA")
```

---

See also [Does PyGame do 3d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865636/does-pygame-do-3d/65618694#65618694), [PyGame and ModernGL library](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame_opengl/moderngl_library/pygame_moderngl_library.md), [PyGame and OpenGL 4](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame_opengl/opengl_4/pygame_opengl_4.md)
 or [PyGame and OpenGL immediate mode (Legacy OpenGL)](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame_opengl/immediate_mode/pygame_opengl_immediate_mode.md).