# pyOpenGL can't create shader

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, shader, pyopengl

I downloaded pyOpenGL and when I import it, my program runs just fine. However, a problem occurs when I try to create a shader. Here is my code:

```
from OpenGL.GL import * 
import OpenGL.GL.shaders
computeShader = OpenGL.GL.glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER)
```

When I try to run this code, it throws this error:  `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`

Does anybody have any idea what is wrong or how I could fix this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must create the OpenGL window and Context before you can create the shader. Every OpenGL command needs an [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context), without a Context it fails. In general, the OpenGL context is created with the OpenGL window. This is a disadvantage of OpenGL (OpenGL is pretty old), you can't create a shader without a window. At least you have to create a hidden window. Use [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news), [glfw](https://pypi.org/project/glfw/) or [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) to create the window. With *glfw* you can create an initially hidden window, *freeglut* is contained within the PyOpenGL package.

To create an OpenGL window with Pygame, you need add the `OPENGL` flag to [`pygame.display.set_mode`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode). e.g.:

```
pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.DOUBLEBUF| pygame.OPENGL)
```

However you need to draw everything with OpenGL. See [How can I draw using pygame, while also drawing with pyopengl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66552579/how-can-i-draw-using-pygame-while-also-drawing-with-pyopengl/66552664#66552664)

Comment: @Matthew What is your OS? What is the OpenGL Context version?

Comment: my os is mac BigSir version 1.4 and when I type the command `print(OpenGL.contextdata.getContext())` it prints -927276032. This doesn't look like an OpenGL context. Am I using the correct command?

Comment: OpenGL version 4.3 is required for compute shaders. Apple does not support this version for dogmatic reasons. See [Compute shaders on a mac](https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl/comments/9wifho/compute_shaders_on_a_mac/)