# How to draw ellipse in 3D plane using Python?

Tags: python

I use this code to draw in 2D plane. I need to draw these ellipses in a 3D .

Here is my code .

```
                      #Elliptical orbits

import pygame
import math
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption("Elliptical orbit")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while(True):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    xRadius = 250
    yRadius = 100
    x2Radius = 100
    y2Radius = 50

    for degree in range(0,360,10):
        x1 = int(math.cos(degree * 2 * math.pi / 360) * xRadius) + 300
        y1 = int(math.sin(degree * 2 * math.pi / 360) * yRadius) + 150
        x2 = int(math.cos(degree * 2 * math.pi / 360) * x2Radius) + 300
        y2 = int(math.sin(degree * 2 * math.pi / 360) * y2Radius) + 150
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), [300, 150], 35)
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, (255, 255, 255), [50, 50, 500, 200], 1)
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, (255, 0, 255), [200, 100, 200, 100], 1)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 255), [x1, y1], 15)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 255), [x2, y2], 5)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(5)
```

Here is the output I get now.
[image]

This is what I want.

[image]

Please let me know if I can do this using Python. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You show some Python code that draws elliptical orbits, and you ask how you can write Python code to draw elliptical orbits? Why don't you use the code you already have?

Comment: What is a "3D plane"? A plane is two-dimensional.

Comment: Hi, I have drawn that in 2D plane. I can only get (x,y) coordinates. I need it in 3D so that I can get (x,y,z) coordinates.

Comment: My mistake. What I meant was "in 3D"

Comment: What was the difficulty when you tried to not only calculate x and y, but also z, coordinates?

Comment: I don't see how to get z coordinates using this.

Comment: Sounds like you need to think more about what you want to actually calculate, and this is not really a programming problem.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I added the picture I want. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Also.. ``pygame`` is not for 3d drawing, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865636/does-pygame-do-3d

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget Thank you. Any other method is also fine.