# How can I do my function duplicate in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I am working on a project that needs a function to be duplicated and not let any space between all the shapes.

Basically, my problem is that I can find the way.

Code:

```py
# importing modules
import pygame
import sys
import random

# colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (4, 255, 0)
brown=  (165,42,42)
# starting pygame
pygame.init()
# making a screen
(width, height) = (500, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Mincraft')
running = True
# fps counter
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
print(clock)
def grass_block(green,brown):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (395, 0, 90,50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, brown, (395, 10, 90,50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, brown, (395, 20, 90,50))
# geting the x button to work
while running:
    grass_block(green,brown)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Side questions id=f someone could transform the rect to a 3d object and make every side with a texture?

Thanks, everyone who responds

Comment: *"Side questions id=f someone could transform the rect to a 3d object and make every side with a texture?"* - Read [Does PyGame do 3d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865636/does-pygame-do-3d/65618694#65618694)

Comment: *"So I am working on a project that needs a function to be duplicated and not let any space between each other"* - I don't think anyone knows what you mean.

Comment: @Rabbid76 how is it now?

Comment: It is still only just telling us what the task is. We don't know what specific problem you're having or what question you want to ask that you can't find any information about.

Comment: @takendarkk Very likely the question is: "How do I create a Minecraft clone using Pygame?". The answer is: "You can not".

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to repeat the grass block so that it can be drawn multiple times you need to make quite a few modifications to your code.

First off why are you making colors you parameters

It is completely unnecessary to have

```
def grass_block(green,brown):
```

instead put the position of the "block" as the parameters
def grass_block(x, y):

Now change your function to reflect these values:

```
def grass_block(x,y):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (x, 0 + y, 90,50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, brown, (x, 10 + y, 90,50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, brown, (x, 20 + y, 90,50))
```

then in you while loop have an additional loop that repeats the method

```
while running:
    for i in range("The amount of block you need to make"):
#this should make another block every repetition to the right of the previous
        grass_block(395 + (90 * i), "starting Y value") 

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: You really should learn a bit more about some of pythons basics, learn about some classes, and how functions work. Some youTube videos would really help you out