# Create 3D RGB Cube with possible rotation

Tags: python, matplotlib, rgb, cube, matplotlib-3d

I want to create/draw a 3D RGB Cube with possibility to rotate it.

Something like this:

[image: picture of 3D RGB Cube]

I assumed that matplotlib would be a good option to create it, because it has built-in rotation function.

I tried something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Full 8-bit RGB space
bits = 8
cube_dimension = 2**bits
full_rgb_space = np.zeros((cube_dimension, cube_dimension, cube_dimension, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Fill the 3D RGB cube
for i in range(cube_dimension):
    for j in range(cube_dimension):
        for k in range(cube_dimension):
            color = (i, j, k)
            full_rgb_space[i, j, k] = color

# Create a figure and 3D axis
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# # Extract the RGB components
r, g, b = full_rgb_space[:, :, :, 0], full_rgb_space[:, :, :, 1], full_rgb_space[:, :, :, 2]
#
# # Reshape the RGB arrays to match the dimensions of the scatter plot
r = r.flatten()
g = g.flatten()
b = b.flatten()
#
# # Create an array of colors for each point
colors = full_rgb_space / 255.0
colors = colors.reshape(-1, 3)
#
# # Display the RGB cube using scatter plot
ax.scatter(r, g, b, c=colors, marker='s')


ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

It even somewhat render what I want, but the problem is that it is so slow / not optimized that even simple rotation takes ages.

I'm afraid I've unfortunately taken the wrong approach to this, but I have no idea how I should do it correctly.

Comment: matplotlib is the wrong library for this as it'll do CPU rendering (although for a simple case like a cube I don't imagine it being difficult if you write optimized code). Try PyGame which allows you to do graphics rendering which is what you intend to do. Issues I see with your code: 1) you're completely filling the cube, even the invisible inside portions of it, which takes a long time ((2^8)^3) = 16,777,216 iterations. You probably only want to draw the (visible) surfaces. 2) Using flatten will ALWAYS result in copying memory, try ravel instead which only creates a copy if it is necessary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865636/does-pygame-do-3d

Answer (score 1):

The simplest example that comes to mind is to use [S3Dlib](https://s3dlib.org/), a Matplotlib third party package, to generate the following:

[image: RGB_cube]

The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import s3dlib.surface as s3d

rgb_cube = s3d.CubicSurface(5).domain([0,1],[0,1],[0,1])
rgb_cube.map_color_from_op(lambda xyz : xyz)
#rgb_cube.map_color_from_op(lambda xyz : 1-xyz)

minmax, ticks = (-0.1,1.1) , [0,1]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d', proj_type='ortho')
ax.set(xlabel='R',  ylabel='G',  zlabel='G',
       xticks=ticks,yticks=ticks,zticks=ticks,
       xlim=minmax, ylim=minmax, zlim=minmax,
       title='RGB Color Space')
ax.add_collection3d(rgb_cube.shade(.5))

plt.show()
```

Note: if the above commented-out code line is used, the CMY color space is plotted.  The S3Dlib documentation also contains figures for [Lab and HSV](https://s3dlib.org/examples/functional/Lab_space.html) color space plots.  In addition, the documentation provides an example of a [Lab space annimation](https://s3dlib.org/examples/animations/anim_lab_rot.html).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the best solution, but at least it works better than previous version.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numberOfPointsInDimension = 64
skip = 256 / numberOfPointsInDimension
cube_dimension = int(256 / skip)
count = 0
# to speed process it replaced counting of elements with constant for some specific dimensions values
if numberOfPointsInDimension == 256:
    count = 390152
elif numberOfPointsInDimension == 128:
    count = 96776
elif numberOfPointsInDimension == 64:
    count = 23816
else:
    for i in range(cube_dimension):
        for j in range(cube_dimension):
            for k in range(cube_dimension):
                if i == 0 or i == cube_dimension-1 or j == 0 or j == cube_dimension-1 or k == 0 or k == cube_dimension-1:
                    count += 1

points = np.zeros((count, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
count = 0
for i in range(cube_dimension):
    for j in range(cube_dimension):
        for k in range(cube_dimension):
            if i == 0 or i == cube_dimension-1 or j == 0 or j == cube_dimension-1 or k == 0 or k == cube_dimension-1:
                color = (i * skip, j * skip, k * skip)
                points[count] = color
                count += 1

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# Set equal aspect ratio for the 3D plot
ax.set_box_aspect([1, 1, 1])
# # Extract the RGB components
r, g, b = points[:, 0], points[:, 1], points[:, 2]
# # Reshape the RGB arrays to match the dimensions of the scatter plot
r = np.ravel(r)
g = np.ravel(g)
b = np.ravel(b)
# # Create an array of colors for each point
colors = points / 255.0
# Display the RGB cube using scatter plot
scaling = 200
ax.scatter(r, g, b, c=colors, marker='s', s=scaling, alpha=1)
ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```